# Convert a Julian date in MySQL to Gregorian date for multiple rows

Tags: mysql, date, julian-date

In my MySQL database I have one column (text) with about 2000 rows. In each row I have a Julian date (like 2457268 for 2015-09-02).

Looking for a solution to update all rows from Julian to Gregorian.

Any way to do this in either SQL or PHP?

Comment: The code sample you posted seems incomplete. You haven't closed the while loop, incremented (or used) the counter or shown us your jd_to_greg() function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [`jdtogregorian()` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.jdtogregorian.php)?

Comment: Yes - I know this function, but can't seem to find a solution how to convert all records.

Answer (score 0):

[staaland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4913668/staaland) originally posted this answer within their question (in [this revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30312663/4)) instead of creating an answer post.

---

> I found the solution myself:
>
> ```
> $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tabel";
> $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
>
> while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery)) {
>
>   $dbDate = $objResult["field1"];
>   $id = $objResult["id"];
>   $date = jd_to_greg($dbDate);
>
>   mysql_query("UPDATE tabel SET `column1` = '$date' WHERE id=$id");
>
> }
> ```